# JavaFX Scene Builder and fx:include

Tags: include, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am wondering how one can use `fx:include` in conjunction with the JavaFX Scene Builder, therefore:

Imagine I have a `BorderPane` (file `borderpane.fxml`). In the center section I want to put a `Label` which shall however be defined in a separate FXML file, e.g. `label.fxml`.

**First problem of this**: As the `label.fxml` will be integrated into a container (the BorderPane) it doesn't need one itself. The SceneBuilder however only offers the option to create layouts being a container?

**Second problem**: I can create the `label.fxml` manually and then adapt `borderpane.fxml` manually to include the `label.fxml`. I then can load the borderpane.fxml file using SceneBuilder without any problems. However when I now change the text of the label and choose "Save", not the `label.fxml` is modified, but instead the `borderpane.fxml` is modified like this:

```
# borderpane.fxml  
<fx:include source="label.fxml" text="the new label text" />
```

The new label text should be written to `label.fxml`, not to `borderpane.fxml`, what is currently done.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is SceneBuilder not intended to be used in conjunction with fx:include?
- I want separate Controllers for parts of my GUI, I think this is quite logically/normal, so this practical usage scenario is hopefully somehow supported by the SceneBuilder?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that [Scene Builder 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) solved both the issue you mentioned.

**First (solved) problem**: the root node doesn't have to be a `Pane`. For example, it can be a `Label`

**Second (solved) problem**: The menu `File > Include > FXML...` can be used to include an external FXML file. It is not possible to edit the included file. Anyway, right-clicking the node in the Document view will show the "Edit included file" menu item, which opens another Scene Builder window for that file.

In conclusion, **Scene Builder 2 correctly handles the `fx:include` element**.

Comment: Nice explanation but there is one problem: if you include the fxml file you can't drag it in scence builder to put it wherever you want in your application!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method of adding nodes to embedded FXML contols using scene builder.

You can do this using Java code however.  If your borderpane.fxml defined a controller with a method called #setCentre to add a node then you could load label.fxml in the parent controller of borderpane.fxml and add the label using the method you have defined.

One question though, are you giving a simplified example or are you actually creating FXML files for labels and border panes?  If so then I think this will actually make your program more complex than just adding controls to a larger control.